# Can't check properties of a program running on startup (Win10)?

Tags: boot, windows-10, task-manager

When I run task manager as administrator on Windows 10, and want to check programs that run on startup, for most of them I can see the properties and location, except for a program called "Program" without any details, for which those options are grayed out, as shown here:

[image: screenshot]

How can I check what this program is and whether I need it?

Comment: I recommend you to use [Sysinternals Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) for inspection startup programs.

Comment: Autoruns was helpful, I had checked the usual registry run locations but forgot about the legacy 32-bit section, which had an uninstalled program in it: \SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run